# Suggestion for multi if factoring

Tags: refactoring

I have some old ugly code like this

```js
if(!isLogin)
{
  if(confirm("Login first ?"))
  {
    doLogin();
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    doStuff1();
    doStuff2();
    doStuff3();
  }
}
else
{
  doStuff1();
  doStuff2();
  doStuff3();
}
```

For refactoring, here's what I did

```js
if(!isLogin && confirm("Login first ?"))
{
  doLogin();
}
else
{
  doStuff1();
  doStuff2();
  doStuff3();
}
```

I'm not sure... is new code logic equals old part, and possible to make it shorter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return;` after `doLogin();` to be the same.  You could drop the `else {` and `}` too, and unindent the three `doStuff?()` functions:

```
if (!isLogin && confirm("Login first ?"))
{
    doLogin();
    return;
}
doStuff1();
doStuff2();
doStuff3();
```